# Show only if x comments?

Tags: comments

Is there any function that will show some content only if there are more than x comments ?
For example show some banner only if more than 10 comments are in post ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_count_comments()` returns the number of comments either for the whole blog or just for the current post.

Example:

```
if ( 10 < wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() )->approved )
    echo 'Wow, more than 10 comments!';
```